# Full Screen UIWebView without status bar cannot scroll to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I removed the top status bar, my UIWebView will not scroll to top, and understandably so. The question is how do I have the tap the top to scroll to top without the status bar?

I know Apple can do this when Safari is in full screen mode during Land scape.  Tap to the invisible area, the content scrolls to top.

Anyone know how Apple does it?

Comment: You could just get the coordinates of the tap on the window and then scroll up programmatically maybe?

Comment: Maybe i can have a clear view on top of my webview and then activate a scroll to top.  But is there such a function?

Comment: I'll try the contentOffset of my webview's scrollview. As the manual says it should work.